# Decode PNG on an ESP8266

Tags: esp8266

I'd like to decode a PNG on an ESP8266 and access to some pixels of the result. Has anyone got experience with PNG on Arduino? Is it feasible at all? I've done some research on PNG decoding libraries, found [UPNG](https://github.com/elanthis/upng). Will check if it can be used in Arduino/ESP.

Comment: `Is it feasable` depends on the the size of your picture, where it stored, and how you want to store the decompressed data. On an ESP8266 you have ~40kB of free RAM and a decoded picture with RGBA8888 format (2 bytes per pixel) and 128x128 px will take 32kB to store the decompressed image. Notice that the libray always decodes whole pictures, not blockwise -- you must be able to fit the complete decoded image into RAM.

Comment: Thanks. Image comes from network stream, base64 encoded (urlData), with a maximum of 128x128 pixels size. I feel this is on the limits.

Comment: If you also have the base64 string of the compressed PNG in RAM (how much % of the original image size is that?), plus network / TCP buffers, this will be quite the tough call. You might have to change your logic to transfer smaller images (either resolution or pixel depth), or directly decoded images so you don't have to decode them. You might want to look into an ESP32 (512K RAM) or the ESP-WROVER (ESP32 + 4 MegaByte PSRAM)

Comment: With those small images and decompression overhead for png, I got the feeling you might be better of sending uncompressed bitmap images instead. Also try avoiding base64, as that makes things 30% larger, or decode the base64 on the fly.

Comment: UPNG is simple to port to a microcontroller. I just did it in an afternoon to run on a 200MHz PIC32MZ with 512kB RAM. It wouldn't run on an 80MHz PIC32MX with 32kB RAM. That's with a 100x100 pixel RGBA8 image. I need to test it with intermediate chips to see what the minimum memory for that image size is.  Also that's with the image source held in flash.

Comment: Update: a 128kB PIC32 works, but not a 64kB - so I'd say you need a couple of hundred kB to work with small images. 128kB is OK for things like small icons held in flash.

Comment: @Majenko I'm now dealing with an ESP32 which I guess is able to decode small PNGs. Would you be so kind and share the version of UPNG you ported? Thanks!

Comment: It's ported to DisplayCore which is for the chipKIT environment. You are welcome to use my code as an example of how to call the UPNG code though.  https://github.com/DisplayCore/PNG